# Why i getting Internal server error in my jquery service call

Tags: jquery

I used simple jquery service call i always getting Internal server error why? please help me. i given my code.**I using VS2005**

Give me details

**Default.aspx**

```
<pre><code>  
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function CallService() {
    $('input[type=button]').attr('disabled', true);
        $("#CustDetails").html('');
        $("#CustDetails").addClass("loading");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "AdvService.asmx/GetCtcDetails",
             data: '{}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",            

            success: OnSuccess,
            error: OnError
        });

        function OnSuccess(data, status) {
            $("#CustDetails").removeClass("loading");
            $("#CustDetails").html(data.d);
            $('input[type=button]').attr('disabled', false);
        }

        function OnError(request, status, error) {
            $("#CustDetails").removeClass("loading");
            $("#CustDetails").html(request.statusText);
            $('input[type=button]').attr('disabled', false);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Body

```
<pre><code>

<form id="DocForm" runat="server">
<div>

    <table style="width:31%;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                Enter Contact ID</td>
            <td>
                :</td>
            <td>
                <input id="txt_id" type="text" />
                <input id="btnGo" type="button" value="Get Details" onclick ="CallService(); return false;"/></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
<br />
<div id="CustDetails" style="width: 60%; height: 75px;">
&nbsp;
   </div>
</div>
</form>
```

```
enter code here
[WebMethod]
public string DisplayMessage()
{
    return "Hello World using jQuery Ajax";
}
```

I used simple jquery service call i always getting Internal server error why? please help me. i given my code.**I using VS2005**

Give me details

Comment: Is call to service working something like http://../AdvService.asmx/GetCtcDetails. Also data parameter should be data:{} (OBJECT) not data: '{}' (STRING),

Comment: Than you elrado data{} is working fine if i want to pass some parameter to service like this data: {'ID': $('#txt_id').val() }, how to do please explain this case. i want get data from database pass the parameter

Answer (score 0):

@lakshman I am not sure that I understand you're request. If you want to pass parameters to service you just do it like

```
data: {
   id: 123,
   name: 'elrado'
}
```

Comment: Thank elrado.i find answer for this

Comment: Thank elrado.i find answer for this                            

    enter code here

  var cartItem = {"ID": $('#txt_id').val()}

        $('input[type=button]').attr('disabled', true);
            $("#CustDetails").html('');
            $("#CustDetails").addClass("loading");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "AdvService.asmx/GetCtcDetails",              
                      data: JSON.stringify(cartItem),
      
                                                                

But now i cant able display what i get from DB.:-(

Comment: where do you want to display it?

Comment: in my UI Page.<div id="CustDetails" style="width: 60%; height: 75px;">
&nbsp;
   </div>
for that i used function OnSuccess(data, status) {
                $("#CustDetails").removeClass("loading");
                $("#CustDetails").html(data.d);                           
                $('input[type=button]').attr('disabled', false);
            }
this function is it correct?

Comment: in OnSuccess try alert (data); or even better include firebug in firefox and try console.log(data);

Comment: Yes i will get data on alert..how to display in UI?

Comment: alert (data.d ) will do whatever you need

Comment: No alert (data.d) giving showing undefined message.if i put alert(data) its working fine.i can able see the display also.. what is the purpose of data.d? can you explain details i want know use of .d

Comment: you are receiving data in json format: {name:'elrado', occupation:'programmer'...}. undefined message means that you'r json has no key named d. Did you copy data.d from some other page?